# Block MQTT port from windows firewall

Tags: windows-11, firewall, port, windows-firewall, mqtt

I want to block any MQTT transaction from my laptop. I am using port 8883 as mqtt port as i am using TLS.

I tried to change the firewall outbound rules and added a new rule to block the connection for port 8883. But the port is not blocked as i tried to connect to mqtt server using mqtt explorer application.